# Using Javascript in TextExpander to validate text on the clipboard and make it Bold

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, textexpander

I'm not sure if this is possible but essentially I haven't been convinced to switch to the new Microsoft Outlook because I value the functionality of VBA. Specifically, I use VBA to always validate specific regex patterns and make them bold in a specific color. I like certain features of the new Microsoft Outlook but the fact that it doesn't allow VBA or MS Scripts seems like a pitfall so I'm trying to see if TextExpander has the capability of this functionality.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Text Expander is not supported at the moment. And there is no official information about whether Text Expander is compatible with the new Outlook version.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.